# Using Factory Girl to create a factory for Thread and Thread Participations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, factory-bot

can someone provide an example or point me to where I can learn how to do Factory Girl nested model associations?

A Thread has to have at least one ThreadParticipation

Right now I have my thread in factories.rb as follows:

```
Factory.define :thread do |thread|
  thread.title             "mythread"
end
```

How do I then create a ThreadParticipation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Getting Started file](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) in the factory_girl source has info on associations.

> Associated instances can be generated
>   by using the association method when
>   defining a lazy attribute:
>
> ```
> factory :post do
>   # ...
>   author 
> end
> ```
>
> You can also specify a different
>   factory or override attributes:
>
> ```
> factory :post do
>   # ...
>   association :author, :factory => :user, :last_name => 'Writely'
> end
> ```

So, in your instance, I would imagine something like this would do:

```
Factory.define :thread do |thread|
  thread.title "mythread"
  thread.thread_participation
end

Factory.define :thread_participation do |ppn|
  ppn.attribute "value"
end
```

If you're using a collection instead of a `has_one`/`belongs_to` association, you can create an array as such:

```
Factory.define :thread do |thread|
  thread.title "mythread"
  thread.thread_participations { |a| [a.association(:thread_participation)] }
end
```

Comment: Thanks but that gives off a "undefined local variable or method thread_participation"

Comment: I'm using the rails 3 factory girl gem, maybe that's why? You have to use Factory.define :thread do |thread|